# Why was Kato's name never changed?

Tags: character, the-green-hornet

In the Green Hornet his partner is Kato. Why did he not have another name when not fighting crime? Like Britt Reid is the Green Hornet, Bruce Wayne /Batman, Dick Grayson/Robin and the list goes on.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Movies and TV SE. Regarding your question, It hasn't given any information why Kato didn't used a different name on when being a masked vigilante, but there are some other characters that uses the same name for real life and as masked superhero, one being The Ray(his real life name is also Ray). Read more about Kato [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kato_(The_Green_Hornet))

Comment: I know 3 reasons why a hero or a sidekick doesn't use real name. 1 is hiding the identification to protect people around them like Spiderman, etc, 2 is making a symbol like Batman, etc and 3 is they are just called by people like Superman. Does Kato really need a name for 1 or more in 3 above purpose?

Comment: There were multiple Katos over the years. Kato was the surname of a whole family of them. https://comicvine.gamespot.com/kato/4005-4767/